# Load testing Besu + IBFT2?

Tags: testing, besu, ibft

The context:
I have a simple app that that consults historic of events frequently. It works fine on my development machine, with just a few thousands blocks. I am not sure if it will continue to work 3 years from now (when millions of blocks could potentially be mined).

Is there any way to create a "mock" IBFT-2 network with, let's say, 8 million initial (random) blocks.

***Update 2020-12-08:***
The answer by "shemnon" (trying to connect to an already existing consortium chain with millions of blocks), partially replies the testing issue, but now my initial question can be reformulated as:
"If I have a current testing network with 20 millions blocks, *Is there any way to create a "mock" IBFT-2 network, with, let's say, 20x10 millions blocks?*

***The idea is to always being able to test with future x10/x100/... blockchain sizes due to the append only/always increasing nature*** of blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

Besu supports Ethereum Mainnet and Ethereum Classic, each with over 11 million blocks, on Proof of Work consensus.  There is also a [consortium chain](https://github.com/lacchain/besu-network) I am aware of that currently has well over 18 million blocks on IBFT2 consensus. These are all production networks.